# working with direct Oracle access components in delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-5

I am creating one delphi application which is fetches data from database. For accessing the database through delphi i am using DOA components. 
Is it possible to run the built exe on any machine? If not then what are the option available? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run your exe on any machine. You only need Oracle client to be installed.

Comment: I am getting error while running the exe. :( DOA components for delphi 5 are free?? As i downloaded from there site and installed on my machine. The error is showing "evaluation version needs delphi " thanks.

Comment: The version you download from the site is an "evaluation" version and will work only if the .exe is run within the IDE. It does not allow it to be distributed. You have to buy it for distribution, they are not free.

Answer (score 0):

The DOA components are *not free* as you can tell by reading [their website](http://www.allroundautomations.nl/doaordering.html). So you'll have to purchase these components, and you'll have to install and configure the Oracle client on each machine.

But they may still be your best option. Alternatively, you can use ADO, but the ADO Oracle driver from Oracle apparently is instable, while the ADO Oracle driver from Microsoft is much stabler, but doesn't support blobs. 
These problems are solved in ADO.NET, but that won't do you any good using Delphi 5.

Comment: I am using delphi 5 professional version and its not having ADO pallets. I think it comes with enterprise edition only. Any other way i can connect to database? thanks

Comment: None that I have experience with. But I wonder, is the price of the DOA components too high for a person/company that also has an Oracle license?